# Running a powershell script using a batch file (.bat)

Tags: command-line, vmware, powershell, batch-file

Currently this is my path for launching VMware vSphere PowerCLI command prompt. I wish to run my sample.ps1 script automatically using a batch file. How can I incoporate sample.ps1 into this path and create a batch file?

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe 
 -psc "C:\Program Files\VMware\Infrastructure\vSphere PowerCLI\vim.psc1" -noe -c 
 ". \"C:\Program Files\VMware\Infrastructure\vSphere PowerCLI\Scripts\Initialize-PowerCLIEnvironment.ps1\""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would want to do is to replace the end of command where it calls out to `Initialize-PowerCLIEnvironment.ps1` and replace that with the path to your sample.ps1 file.

You will almost certainly need to have the first line of your sample file be the original reference to `Initialize-PowerCLIEnvironment.ps1` such that the initialization code (most likely function/cmdlet definitions) is run prior to any of your code that may depend on it.

For example, the contents of your sample.ps1 file would look something like this:

```
# source vSphere PowerCLI Environment first
. "C:\Program Files\VMware\Infrastructure\vSphere PowerCLI\Scripts\Initialize-PowerCLIEnvironment.ps1"
# custom code follows
$me = "Hello, vSphere and PowerCLI!!!"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo off

Title,Sample Script &color 9e

for /f "usebackq delims=$" %%a in (`cd`) do (
  set SCRIPTDIR=%%a
)

(Set ScriptFile=%SCRIPTDIR%\Sample.ps1)

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -psc "C:\Program Files\VMware\Infrastructure\vSphere PowerCLI\vim.psc1" -c ". \"C:\Program Files\VMware\Infrastructure\vSphere PowerCLI\Scripts\Initialize-PowerCLIEnvironment.ps1\";%ScriptFile%"
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.